# reshelving files after a change in new shelve

Tags: perforce

I added edited files after doing the following:

```
p4 edit file1
p4 edit file2
```

Then, I shelve them using:

```
p4 shelve
```

Now, I went to the files and made changes to them. After that I want to add the opened files and shelve them with another number. What I do is that I add them individually to the change list using

```
p4 reopen -c default file1
p4 reopen -c default file2
p4 shelve
```

But because I have a lot of files in many directories. This takes forever. Is there is an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

p4 reopen takes a pattern.

If you want to reopen **all** your opened files into the default changelist, simply do "p4 reopen -c default //..."

If you want to reopen a certain set of those files, do "p4 reopen -c default file1 file2 file3 directory/file1", or, if you can specify a pattern: "p4 reopen -c default file*"

See: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/reopen.html#1040665

Answer (score 1):

if you can enumerate the list of files easily, then you can at least automate the command using xargs.

`cat filelist | xargs -n 1 p4 reopen -c default`

If filelist contains:

```
file1
file2
file3
directory/file1
```

then the above command will run

```
p4 reopen -c default file1
p4 reopen -c default file2
p4 reopen -c default file3
p4 reopen -c default directory/file1
```